# Palavra portuguesa para ''Quantile'' (Eng.)

Tags: estrangeirismos

A língua inglesa tem a palavra [Quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile). Existe alguma palavra portuguesa para o mesmo significado? Já ouvi a palavra "quantil", mas não encontro a sua entrada no priberam...

Comment: Eu acho que é "Quantil", embora também não encontre no dicionário.

Comment: Resposta [Quantil](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantil)

Comment: @AndréLyra também me parecia... porque razão não aparece nos dicionários?

Comment: @Anold também gostava de saber... É estranho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantil é a palavra que você procura. A aprendi numa classe de Estatística nos meus tempos de Universidade.

Porém dizia-se que vários termos do jargão de estatística foram cunhados a partir de erros de tradução de livros de origem inglesa.

Comment: Obrigado. Ainda que não encontre no dicionário, várias pessoas já me disseram que era quantil, o que para mim é suficiente. ;)